# PageMethods to retrieve session from page in iframe not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

2 pages. Uploader.aspx and Uploadee.aspx.

Uploadee.aspx is in an iframe on Uploader.aspx.

This is the markup for Uploader.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Uploader.aspx.cs" Inherits="Uploader" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doupload()
    {
        document.getElementById('spFN').innerHTML = 'Document upload in progress.';
        window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();

        intervalID = window.setInterval(function ()
        {
            PageMethods.GetUploadStatus(function (result)
            {
                if (result)
                {
                    alert(result.fileNumber);
                    document.getElementById('spFN').innerHTML = 'Uploading file ' + result.fileNumber;
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    }  
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    <span onclick="doupload();">Try it</span> <span id="spFN"></span>
    <iframe id="uploadFrame" frameborder="0" height="400" width="800" scrolling="yes" src="Uploadee.aspx"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to read the value of a session variable from the page in the iframe. Here is the code in the page behind of the page in the iframe (uploadee.aspx).

```
    public partial class Uploadee : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Session["FN"] = i.ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I am in a loop increasing the session variable - Session["FN"] - by 1 each iteration.

In the code behind of the page that contains the iframe, I have this:

```
 #region Web Methods
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static object GetUploadStatus()
{
    string fileNumber = HttpContext.Current.Session["FN"].ToString();
    return new
    {
        fileNumber = fileNumber
    };

}
#endregion
```

So, the process is: I click on the 'Try it' span on the containing page - Uploader.aspx - and this calls javascript function doupload()

This submits the form on the page in the iframe. When this form submits, the loop is run that increases the value of the Session["FN"] variable. At the same time, PageMethods.GetUploadStatus should be querying the value of Session["FN"] every 500 milliseconds.

BUT, the only time the alert in PageMethods.GetUploadStatus is shown, is AFTER all the iterations of the loop. It retrieves the value of Session["FN"] okay - but only once and only after the page in the iframe has finished processing.

I keep reading that I should be able to do what I am trying to do ... any help much appreciated. This is driving me nuts. Apologies for length of post.

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net session state handles concurrent requests to the same session in a special way:

> if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the
>   same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the
>   session information. The second request executes only after the first
>   request is finished.

The above is from an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

You could possibly create your own [SessionStateProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) that handles concurrency in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any idea why/how this works ...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113418/ASP-NET-File-Upload-with-Progress-Bar

Comment: Got it working by adding EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" Async="true" to the page in the iframe.

Don't understand ... you would think that EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" would mean you can only read from Session ... but I am writing to the Session in a loop and now, the page containing the iframe can access the Session variable value as it changes. Odd - but still, it works.